# I sent an SMS containing these special characters: ă, â, î, ș, ț and received it unchanged. How is it possible?

Tags: sms

I have a Nokia Lumia 520 running Windows Phone 8.1.

I sent an SMS to myself (in a foreign language) containing these special characters: **ă, â, î, ș, ț** and received the text unchanged. **How is it possible** as long as the [GSM 03.38 Character Set](https://www.csoft.co.uk/support/character-sets#gsm_set) does not contain the above mentioned letters? (I even got a text from the mobile phone operator confirming the message was delivered to my phone number.)

**Will the characters ă, â, î, ș, ț be received as they are if I send SMSs to other peoples in various countries?**

As a note: My opportunity to send such texts to real people are rare so I can not simply do tests now and see if they receive the SMSs unaltered.

Comment: I have done some more tests and it appears I can send ă, â, î, ș, ț or other unusual special signs but the maximum allowed length of an SMS will be shortened from 160 to just  70 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Phone and Windows 10 Mobile (like most modern phone systems) support Unicode SMS, where messages that contain non-ASCII characters are instead sent in a different character set (almost certainly either UTF-8 or UTF-16; I'm not fully sure). When sending Unicode SMS, each character takes up more space in the limited buffer allocated for SMS (which is only 140 bytes per message; 160 ASCII characters is achieved by throwing away the high bit of each character and packing the characters 7 bits at a time instead of spacing them out to 8-bit bytes). That's why you are limited to a shorter number of characters per message, and why some more esoteric characters (like emoji) take up multiple characters' worth of space (they require multi-byte Unicode values).